How to create a typescript type that can have any arbitrary key and value but error for possibly undefined?
I want to create a type AnyObject that can have any arbitrary key and value but error for possibly undefined.
const a = {} as AnyObject
console.log(a.b?.c) // This should be fine
console.log(a.b.c)  // This should give a possibly undefined error


And it can be nested, with arrays and functions, like with HTML nodes:
node.children?.[0]?.value

node.properties.onClick

Ofcourse this doesn't work (it doesn't error in a.b.c):
type AnyObject = {
  [key: string]: any | undefined
}


Does this approach meet your needs? If so I'll write an answer explaining or find a duplicate; if not, what's missing?

Ok from your starting code, I came up with this solution:
type AnyObject = {
  [key: string]: Omit<undefined,any>;
}

const a:AnyObject = {
    key:null,
    key2:undefined,
    aa:'aa',
    bb:1,
    structuredObject:{

    },
    structuredObject2:{
        'aa':'aa',
        test_boolean:true,
        test_aw_func: () => {},
        test_func: function(){}
    }
}

Which can be tested on this playground: Playground TS
You can extend Omit<undefined,any> with Omit<undefined,any> | null in case you want null values also.

Omit<undefined, any> doesn't mean anything having to do with undefined or any. It's a weird weird way of writing {}. Can you [edit] to articulate what you were going for with this?
